# Question on how to pull templates from account

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Please excuse me for asking what is probably an easy question.  I am trying to use a Template that I created in my DocuSign account.  I am using C# and using the Nuget package api.  I am needing to get the template so that I can fill it out and send the envelope.  I can send out an envelope just fine, I am now trying to just make it look better by using the template option.

As I stated above, I have the complete process working, I am just trying to use the Templates now rather than a document that I am building through HTML.  I have looked all through the Nuget API and everything I see for getting Templates looks like it has to be from an existing document.  All I am trying to do is get a list of templates, select the one that I want and then fill in the fields appropriately then send the document.  Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See our example code here - https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg009UseTemplateController.cs

Let me copy/paste the relevant code into here:

string DoWork (string signerEmail, string signerName, string ccEmail,
            string ccName, string accessToken, string basePath,
            string accountId, string templateId)
        {
            // Data for this method
            // signerEmail 
            // signerName
            // ccEmail
            // ccName
            // accessToken
            // basePath
            // accountId
            // templateId

```
        var config = new Configuration(new ApiClient(basePath));
        config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(config);
        EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName, templateId);
        EnvelopeSummary result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
        return result.EnvelopeId;
    }

    private EnvelopeDefinition MakeEnvelope(string signerEmail, string signerName, 
        string ccEmail, string ccName, string templateId)
    {
        // Data for this method
        // signerEmail 
        // signerName
        // ccEmail
        // ccName
        // templateId

        EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        env.TemplateId = templateId;

        TemplateRole signer1 = new TemplateRole();
        signer1.Email = signerEmail;
        signer1.Name =  signerName;
        signer1.RoleName = "signer";

        TemplateRole cc1 = new TemplateRole();
        cc1.Email = ccEmail;
        cc1.Name = ccName;
        cc1.RoleName = "cc";

        env.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole> { signer1, cc1 };
        env.Status = "sent";
        return env;
    }
    // ***DS.snippet.0.end
```

Comment: thanks for the assist I got that portion of it up and going.  If you don't mind I have 1 more question.  Now that I can access the template how do I fill in the custom text fields?  I am currently doing like this envelopeDefinition.CustomFields = new CustomFields()
{
  TextCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField>()
  {
    new TextCustomField()
    {
     Name = "BillingEmail",
     Value = docuSignInformation.BillingContactEmail
    }
 }
} however when I do this nothing is going through.  Thanks again